# External API in Laravel 5.6. Syncing data to my own database through queued jobs, using model, controller or something else?

Tags: laravel, rest, api, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

My app will sync data from an external service using their REST api. My plan is to periodically update/create data in my database from theirs.

I see a lot of talk about using models as the interface to an external API. I see how this would work when you are using the external API in the same way as a database. i.e. getting data on the fly.

In my case I plan to run scheduled jobs.

Can I ask some advice on how you would suggest setting this up? Currently I have:

- A ExternalProvider API class within my App/Library folder.
- A model that can interact with the database where the external api providers data will be stored.

Should interaction with the API be through another model or a controller, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

The scheduling can be handled with Laravel's [Task Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling):

```
// add a cron job
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1


// add your tasks to the schedule function
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // scheduled a queued job to run every 30 minutes
    $schedule->job(new SyncRemoteApiData)->everyThirtyMinutes();
}
```

Creating models representing the API responses is a good idea, especially of you structure your local database tables in the shape of the response payloads.

If not, they still provide a convenient place to map your schema to theirs. Plus you get all the benefits of what the Eloquent model class brings.

I would do the majority of the logic in Job classes, however. There probably isn't much (any) need for controllers if this is automated and your application is the initiator.